Why is there a huge difference in electron speed when an electron pulses vs. in a conducting wire?
I just read that "Physicists have created the world’s fastest microscope, and it’s so quick that it can spot electrons in motion (when electrons pulse, whatever that means).....This is is quite a feat: Electrons travel at roughly 1367 miles per second (2,200 kilometers per second), making them capable of circumnavigating the Earth in only 18.4 seconds." I had always thought that this is how fast electrons always move.  And I assume the above quote references the speed electrons while transitioning from one orbital (or energy level) within an atom or molecule to another orbital/enegry level within the same atom/molecule.
THEN, to my surprise, I started reading about electric current, and found that the speed of electrons in a conducting metal wire is not very fast at all, and is just ordinary speed.
Why is there this huge discrepancy between discrpency in electron speed in each situation and what factors determine electron speed?
Thanks for any insight.
I have always thought of electrons switching energy levels within its atom/molecule (or even a piece of metal) at near the speed of light, so it confused me to see that the speed of electrons in conducting wire is slow.   I am not sure why this is the case or what factors play a part in this difference.

The article seems to have been at least slightly misleading because 2,200 kilometers per second is a speed that virtually any particle can be made to travel, and a speed at which electrons don't always travel. Could you give more context from the article on what the electrons were doing while the physicists were watching?

I'm not going to explain electron drift velocity--that's a whole condensed matter thing, but I'll try to explain why it makes sense.
Using SI units, the density of copper is:
$$ \rho = 8940\,{\rm kg/m^3} $$
for a number denisty:
$$ \rho_N  = \frac{\rho}{Am_u N_A} \approx 31\,{\rm k mol/m^3}$$
Let's take residential wire as 14-gauge (rated to $I_{max}=15$ amps). It's cross section is:
$$ a = 2\times 10^{-6}\,{\rm m^2} $$
so a $l=1$ meter length has:
$$ N = al\rho_n = 0.6\,{\rm mol} $$
copper atoms in it, and with one conduction electron per atom $n_e=1$, the number of electrons is:
$$ N_e = N n_e  = 0.6\,{mol}$$
for linear charge density of:
$$ \lambda = eN_e N_A= 60\,{kC} $$
If they move faster than:
$$ v = \frac{I_{max}}{\lambda} \approx \frac 1 4\,{\rm mm/s} $$
the circuit breaker pops.
Were they moving at $V=2200\,$km/s, the current would be:
$$ I=\lambda C \approx 130\,{GA} $$
With a resistance of $R=2.6e-3\,\Omega$/m, that 1m of wire would dissipate:
$$ P = I^2R = 4\times 10^{19} W $$
Yikes.
Now, per electron, the kinetic energy of what you called "a pulse":
$$ E = \frac 1 2 m_e V^2 = 2.2\times 10^{-18}\,{\rm J} = 13.8\,{\rm eV}$$
which is a Rydberg? Is that how you picked the speed?
Anyway, that's enough to ionize hydrogen, so it's clearly above room temperature (which is 1/40 eV, btw).
So at room temp, they're moving:
$$ v_{room} = V\sqrt{
\frac{
\frac 1{40}\,{\rm eV}
}
{1\,{\,Ry}}
}\approx 93\,{\rm km/s}$$
...if they were free. They are not. They're stuck to N2 molecules, so:
$$ v \rightarrow v \times \frac{m_e}{28m_u} \approx 1.8\,{\rm km/s}$$
idk...that seems too fast, since:
$$ \frac 3 2 kT = \frac 1 2 m\bar v^2 = 500\,{\rm m/s}$$
not sure where those diverged. I'd go with the 2nd number.
